# Automatic regex builder

Tags: regex, algorithm

I have N strings. 
Also, there are K regular expressions, unknown to me. Each string is either matching one of the regular expressions, or it is garbage. There are total of L garbage strings in the set. Both K and L are unknown.

I'd like to deduce the regular expressions. Obviously, this problem has infinite number of solutions. I need to find a "reasonably good solution", which

1) minimizes K

2) minimizes L

3) maximizes "specifics" of the regular expressions. I don't know what't the right term for this quality. For example, the string "ab123" can be described as /ab\d+/ or /\w+.+/, but the first regex is more "specific".

All 3 requirements need to be taken as one compound criteria, with certain reasonable weights.

A solution for one particular case: If L = 0 and K = 1 (just one regex, and no garbage), then we can just find LCS (longest common subsequence) for the strings and come up with a corresponding regex from there. However, when we have "noise" (L > 0), this approach doesn't work.

Any ideas (or pointers to existing work) are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the information given? Just the N strings? Is the regex's already decided, but just hidden from you? You could easily generate a regex that matches a specific set of strings by joining them with "|".

Comment: :) that would be cheating. I guess I need another criteria to prevent this kind of solution... Restrict the regex lenth, I guess.

Comment: Your condition #3 can better be described as minimizing the number of matching strings that aren't in the given set of N strings. Given that you've got 3 things to minimize (although you could just as easily require L=0), you need to weight which factors are more important.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is *language learning* or *language inference* with a twist: instead of **generalising** over a set of given examples (and possibly counter-examples), you wish to infer a language with a small yet **specific** grammar.

I'm not sure how much research is being done on that. However, if you are also interested in finding the minimal (= general) regular expression that accepts all *n* strings, search for papers on [MDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_description_length) (Minimum Description Length) and [FSMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine) (Finite State Machines).

Two interesting queries at [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/):

- ["minimum description length" automata](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22minimum+description+length%22+automata)
- ["language inference" automata](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22language+inference%22+automata)

Comment: Thanks! Will check papers on MDL.

Answer (score 1):

The key words in academia are "grammatical inference". Unfortunately, there aren't any efficient, general algorithms to do the sort of thing you're proposing. What's your real problem?

Edit: it sounds like you might be interested in Data Description Languages. PADS (http://www.padsproj.org/) is a typical example.

Comment: > What's your real problem?

As a hobby project, I'm implementing a "magic editor" for big files, mostly data (plus occasional comments or "irregularities"). Quite often I need to change formatting, or remove a column of values, or something like this. Usually I do this kind of stuff with a quick perl one-liner. However, I wanted to create a more "visual" solution for people not familiar with regexes. They would just edit one line, and the other (similar) lines in the file change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing clever here, perhaps I don't fully understand the problem?

Why not just always reduce L to 0?  Check each string against each regex; if a string doesn't match any of the regex's, it's garbage.  if it does match, remember the regex/string(s) that did match and do LCS on each L = 0, K = 1 to deduce each regex's definition.

Comment: I don't have any regexes to start with. The problem to deduce them.